# How to make docker use aufs in CentOS 7?

Tags: docker

Where's the location to docker configuration file?

I've tried modifying /etc/sysconfig/docker with options:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-s aufs --fixed-cidr=10.1.1.0/26 --bip=10.1.1.62"
```

docker info shows

```
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:1-2149483840-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Data file: /mnt/ext4/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /mnt/ext4/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 307.2 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 733.2 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

How can I make Storage Driver: aufs? Please help. Thanks

Comment: You don't. (And you don't _want_ to use aufs.) Just use devicemapper. But set it up for real instead of these testing-grade loopback files.

Comment: device mappers are limited to 10gb, i've set up with btrfs to remove the limitations but i check that btrfs is slower than aufs and overlayfs so i think i'll go with ubuntu host and centos container

Comment: devicemapper is not limited to 10GB. I have no idea how you got that idea. And Ubuntu is not a very good platform for Docker overall...or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install a kernel that supports AUFS.

I maintain one here: https://github.com/bnied/rhel-aufs-kernel

Comment: Seems like RHEL/CentOS 7.1+ is moving forward with OverlayFS (and [supposedly Ubuntu didn't even want to support AUFS (circa 2012)](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-March/034880.html)) but belatedly seems to have landed in it anyways. See also https://github.com/AkihiroSuda/docker-issues/ (relates to distros, kernels, and fs)